# Xenial servers offline after unattended upgrades

Tags: apt, server, dpkg, unattended-upgrades

We logged on this morning to find 12 of our servers offline.

All with different hosting companies. All running Xenial.

They all came back online after rebooting and it seems to have been caused by unattended upgrade failure.

Every server shows dpkg was interrupted.

```
root@HMPBgZ:~# apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Every server seems to have crashed on package `libjson-c2`

The MD5SUM of the package is correct.

Running `dpkg --configure -a` locks up the server and requires it be rebooted again

```
root@HMPBgZ:~$ dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libjson-c2:amd64 (0.11-4ubuntu2.1) ...
-- locks up and needs to be rebooted --
```

Attempting to manually install package results in same lockup and we have to reboot.

Has anyone got any idea how to resolve this?

Until we have a solution we're disabling unattended upgrades across all servers and hoping there are no major security issues since we cannot upgrade anything.

Comment: Please file a bug report!

Comment: Appears there is already a bug report and they've reverted back to a previous release.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/json-c/+bug/1878723

Comment: They state that the bug has been fixed.  Have you tried running it again on one of the systems since then?

Comment: It does _not_ fix our issue.

I've commented on the bug.

Manually installing the package results in same server lockup requiring reboot and leaves system in inconsistent state

```
root@HMPBgZ:~# dpkg -s libjson-c2
Package: libjson-c2
Status: install ok half-configured

Version: 0.11-4ubuntu2.2
Config-Version: 0.11-4ubuntu2

```

Comment: Downgrading (and then pinning) to previous version fixes issue for us 'right now' until they fix things upstream.

Comment: They have updated again on how to remove the affected package and then update it again.  Posted 4 hours ago.

Comment: @Dan I triggered the close vote because it is a bug (and a confirmed one) of an active Ubuntu release when 1st posted. OP has clearly mention that he/she is not look for a workaround. So best was to close at that time as it should be in Launchpad instead.